# Display Tinybox 2 popup box on page load

Tags: popup

How Display [Tinybox 2](http://www.scriptiny.com/2011/03/javascript-modal-windows/) Popup box on page load?

Comment: By simply including the code to display it on the page.  Any JavaScript encountered on the page will be immediately executed as it's loaded.  What have you tried, and in what way does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code on page on which you want to Display [Tinybox 2](http://www.scriptiny.com/2011/03/javascript-modal-windows/) Popup box on page load

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function()
   {
      TINY.box.show(html:'You content go here', 1, 400, 350, 1)
   }
</script>
```

To close Popup box after specific time use this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function()
   {
      TINY.box.show('contentfile.html', autohide:20, 1, 400, 350, 1)
   }
</script>
```

This will close popup after 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

i did it this way.

```
   window.onload = function()
   {
        TINY.box.show({
            url: '/message.html',
            width: 403, height: 200, opacity: 20
       });

   }
```